# Errors in RESTful web service implementation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

As a beginner in Web services, I am using [this](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-rs/create-a-simple-restful-web-service-using-jersey-jax-rs/) example to start out with RESTful web services. But, in this case, I have performed every action as it is mentioned till 13th step. But, Unable to proceed further since, I'm not getting the result as they have mentioned in it. I'm getting below error in Firefox `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:9999` Can anyone please help me with this??

Comment: are you sure that server is running at 9999 port?

Comment: @csn : When I tried using 8080 (server port number) it also gives me error. Since I use JBoss server, i tried with JNDI port. Its was giving me some wierd characters as follows `¬í�sr�java.rmi.MarshalledObject|½—ícü>�I�hash[�locBytest�[B[�objBytesq�~�xp›$¹Ïur�[B¬óøTà��xp���*¬í�t�http://exiblr-d-194:8083/q�~��q�~��uq�~����À¬í�sr� org.jnp.server.NamingServer_Stub���������xr�java.rmi.server.RemoteStubéþÜÉ‹áe��xr�java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectÓa´‘a3��xpw4�UnicastRef2�� 10.2.1.21��JŸ´ÂÐàOÛ®*��Cèš(t€�x`

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the Java application acting as the server (CalcRESTStartup) is able to run correctly.
- Then check that the port where it is bind is 9999 (or if you has chosen a different one put that port in the FF URL).
- If all above seems ok, try a telnet to that port, with the server **stopped** and then again with the server running ( The first telnet should fail, and the second succeed).

This is the output when failing:

```
telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

This is the output when succeeding:

```
telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

You can quickly check how this works running the simple http server from python with:

```
python3 -m http.server 9999
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 9999 ..
```

If none of this works, check if there is some firewall preventing connections, or an Operating System policy forbidding opening a listening port.